# Create white Image using javacv

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I want to create a white image having the dimensions of another IplImage.
I know the function to create a black image . 
this is the code :

```
       IplImage whiteImg = IplImage.create(sourceImage.width(),
            sourceImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
       cvSetZero(whiteImg);
```

I want to create from the sourceImage white image in the same dimensions;

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try the code

```
     cvSetZero(whiteImg);
     cvNot(whiteImg,whiteImg);
```

Comment: cvNot takes 2 params I tried this and it works cvNot(whiteImg,whiteImg) thanks.